# PHP setting of datetime field in CCK through Rules, How to stop continuous updates?

Tags: entities, rules, datetime

Drupal 6. Using Rules and CCK

So, I have a content type that gets automatically generated with Rules. Several CCK fields get populated at creation time, including a datetime field. I want this field to get populated with the current date/time.

For some reason, the Global Token fields don't work, the interface throws an error when I try to use a token instead of a standard formatted date/time stamp.

So, I use advanced PHP code box to set the date/time value.

return array(
0 => array('value' => date("m/d/Y - H:i")),
);

This code works, but when I do it this way it seems that whenever I refresh the node page the date/time stamp in the field is updated to whatever the current time is. This is not the behavior I want. I want the date/time to get inserted at creation time, and have it remain unchanged for perpetuity.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just a thought...why not use `$node->created` instead of having a custom field with identical data?

Comment: I'll look into it. The PHP aspect of Drupal is not my strong point.

Comment: Still, there are areas where I will need to set a date/time value for a custom field, above and beyond just the node creation date. I'm talking about additional metadata.

Comment: Yeah fair point. I can't think of any good reason why a node creation rule would be run on a node view though, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: It seems to me (not expert) that the CCK field's value is set to the PHP code. So, whenever the Node page gets refreshed in the browser the field value gets retrieved (the PHP code) and the PHP code happens to dynamically get the timestamp of *right now*. Is that how Drupal node/CCK should operate with PHP input?

Comment: I can't say for sure (I've never actually used them) but that sounds very much like what's happening

Comment: I just tested using your $node-> created suggestion, and it does the same thing.

Comment: I used this PHP code to assign the date value to the CCK field --- return array(0 => array('value' => $node->created)); --- it set the date properly, but when I refreshed the web page a minute later, the field updated and then had the current time.

Comment: Hmm. Could it be a db issue? Has the column somehow been created as a MySQL timestamp (which updates when the record is accessed)?

Comment: Ah! I think that was it. There were several similar seeming Date/Time field types available to use, I was using one called "datetime". I switched to another one called "datestamp" and the datestamp field retained its original value after refreshing. I guess the "datetime" field is designed to always return the current datetime value of now(). Thanks for helping me work through this friend!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Clive's help, I determined the problem was with the field type. There were several similar seeming Date/Time field types available to use, I was using one called "datetime". I switched to another one called "datestamp" and the datestamp field retained its original value after refreshing. I guess the "datetime" field is designed to always return the current datetime value of now(). Thanks for helping me work through this friend!